# Calculate the part of duration in each year

Tags: r, date, duration

I have a dataset df with three variables: id, startyr (start date), and endyr (end date). I need to calculate the duration that occurs each year. For example, for 2023.50-2024.50, I want to assign 0.5 years to 2023 and 0.5 years to 2024. Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

```
id<-rep(c(1:100),times=1)
startyr <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 2024, sd = 1)
endyr <- startyr + 0.325 
df <- data.frame(id, startyr, endyr )
df %>% print()

#      id  startyr    endyr
# 1     1 2023.067 2023.392
# 2     2 2024.936 2025.261
# 3     3 2025.173 2025.498
# 4     4 2024.615 2024.940
# 5     5 2023.747 2024.072
```

The ideal output would be:

```
#     id  startyr    endyr dur2023  dur2024  dur2025  dur2026 
#      X 2023.5     2024.5   0.5     0.5         0      0
#      Y 2024.15     2026.15   0     0.85        1      0.15
```

Comment: What is your expected output? It could be doubling the rows or adding extra columns.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added some details to clarify.

Comment: So you want all years that appear in start and end to be listed as columns?

Comment: That may become a very wide data frame...

Comment: Where does 0.85 come from?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a wide format. to get the 0.85, I used 2025-2024.15

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the output should look like, but you could try:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(first_year = floor(startyr),
         yr1_time = ifelse(floor(endyr) == first_year,
                                      endyr - first_year, 
                                      ceiling(startyr) - startyr),
         second_year = ifelse(floor(endyr) == first_year, 
                              NA, floor(endyr)),
         yr2_time = ifelse(is.na(second_year), 
                                   NA, endyr - floor(endyr))
         )
#>      id  startyr    endyr first_year   yr1_time second_year   yr2_time
#> 1     1 1999.922 2000.247       1999 0.07815307        2000 0.24684693
#> 2     2 2017.000 2017.325       2017 0.32527941          NA         NA
#> 3     3 2029.283 2029.608       2029 0.60783361          NA         NA
#> 4     4 2038.978 2039.303       2038 0.02214540        2039 0.30285460
#> 5     5 2024.943 2025.268       2024 0.05736088        2025 0.26763912
#> 6     6 2006.833 2007.158       2006 0.16688110        2007 0.15811890
#> 7     7 2042.866 2043.191       2042 0.13373396        2043 0.19126604
#> 8     8 2022.118 2022.443       2022 0.44290321          NA         NA
#> 9     9 2038.822 2039.147       2038 0.17790521        2039 0.14709479
#> 10   10 2002.571 2002.896       2002 0.89621835          NA         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this! It's very close to what I was thinking and sorry for the confusion. Is there a way to combine the year and duration of that year into one variable? Like the output that I just added to the question.

Comment: @llxx2021 but that means every year in your data frame would need a column. This would be a very wide data frame.

Comment: Yes, it would be in a wide format. But the real dataset I'm working with, only had data over 10 years so it shouldn't be that bad. I also made the range narrower in the example dataset by changing the SD of the startyr to 1.